# Dynamically create AWS SQS DLQ

Tags: terraform, amazon-sqs, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to alter my AWS SQS module:

This is the before:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "main" {
  name      = var.queue_name
  
  redrive_policy         = jsonencode({
    deadletterTargetArn  = aws_sqs_queue.aws-sqs-deadletter-queue.arn
    maxReceiveCount      = 4
  })
  redrive_allow_policy   = jsonencode({
    redrivePermission    = "byQuery"
    sourceQueueArns      = [aws_sqs_queue.aws-sqs-deadletter-queue.arn]
  })
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "aws-sqs-deadletter-queue" {
  name      = var.deadletter_queue_name
}
```

This validates fine and works.  However, I want to make the creation of the DLQ dynamic (may or may not want a DLQ), so I tried to add a dynamic block:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "main" {
  name      = var.queue_name
  
  dynamic "enable_dlq" {
    for_each = var.enable_dlq ? [1] : []

    redrive_policy         = jsonencode({
      deadletterTargetArn  = aws_sqs_queue.aws-sqs-deadletter-queue[0].arn
      maxReceiveCount      = 4
    })
    redrive_allow_policy   = jsonencode({
      redrivePermission    = "byQuery"
      sourceQueueArns      = [aws_sqs_queue.aws-sqs-deadletter-queue[0].arn]
    })
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "aws-sqs-deadletter-queue" {
  count     = var.enable_dlq ? 1 : 0
  name      = var.deadletter_queue_name
}
```

In this case `var.enable_dlq` is a boolean value passed in.

However, when I attempt to validate this, TF fails with a:

```
Error: Unsupported block type
  on main.tf line xx, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "main":
  xx: dynamic "enable_dlq" {

Blocks of type "enable_dlq" are not expected here.
```

Can a dynamic block statement not be part of "aws_sqs_queue" or did I define it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to implement a [dynamic block](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) with the name "enable_dlq". In Terraform, a dynamic block is a dynamic version of a block property in a resource. Your code doesn't work because you are trying to invent a new block property for the `aws_sqs_queue` resource type.

Further, the `aws_sqs_queue` resource type doesn't even have any block properties. So you won't be able to use the dynamic block syntax here for what you are trying to do. The `redrive_policy` and `redrive_allow_policy` properties expect JSON strings, not Terraform blocks. To set them dynamically you need to simply set them to a JSON string, or `null`. I would do something like this:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "main" {
  name      = var.queue_name
  
  redrive_policy         = var.enable_dlq ? jsonencode({
    deadletterTargetArn  = aws_sqs_queue.aws-sqs-deadletter-queue[0].arn
    maxReceiveCount      = 4
  }) : null

  redrive_allow_policy   = var.enable_dlq ? jsonencode({
    redrivePermission    = "byQuery"
    sourceQueueArns      = [aws_sqs_queue.aws-sqs-deadletter-queue[0].arn]
  }) : null
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "aws-sqs-deadletter-queue" {
  count     = var.enable_dlq ? 1 : 0
  name      = var.deadletter_queue_name
}
```